# stop face recognition in python as soon as face recognized

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

this is my code. it detects the faces and recognize the faces. but i want it to stop as soon as the face is recognized. More clearly as soon as the face is detected recognizer should try to recognize it and after recognizing it, it should not do it again and again. 
in short, for every face detected fisherface should run only once(for every face).

```
# facerec.py
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
import json
size = 4
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'att_faces'
path2='/home/irum/Desktop/Face-Recognition/thakarrecog/UNKNOWNS'
path='/home/irum/Desktop/Face-Recognition/thakarrecog/att_faces'
# Part 1: Create fisherRecognizer
print('Training...')

# Create a list of images and a list of corresponding names
(images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)

for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(fn_dir):
    for subdir in dirs:
        names[id] = subdir 

        subjectpath = os.path.join(fn_dir, subdir) 

        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):
            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
            lable = id
            images.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            lables.append(int(lable))
        id += 1

(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)

# Create a Numpy array from the two lists above
(images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]]

# OpenCV trains a model from the images

model = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
model.train(images, lables)

# Part 2: Use fisherRecognizer on camera stream
haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
# Capturing camera feed
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
while True:
    # Reading Frames from live stream
    (rval, frame) = webcam.read()
    frame=cv2.flip(frame,1,0)
    #Convert frame into gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    # Resize the gary 
    mini = cv2.resize(gray, (gray.shape[1] / size, gray.shape[0] / size))
    # Detecting the face 
    faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini,1.3, 5)
    for i in range(len(faces)):
        face_i = faces[i]
        (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]
        # Croping face
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))
        # Eualize Histogram
        eq = cv2.equalizeHist(face_resize)

        # Try to recognize the face

        prediction  = model.predict(eq)
        print "Recognition Prediction" ,prediction
        # Draw rectangle around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

        # Write the name of recognized face

        result = {
                    'face': {

                            'distance': prediction,
                            'coords': {
                               'x': str(faces[0][0]),
                               'y': str(faces[0][1]),
                               'width': str(faces[0][2]),
                               'height': str(faces[0][3])
                                }
                           }
              }
        print "1 Result of Over all Prediction" ,result


        if prediction[0]>0 and prediction[1]<600:

             result = {
                'face': {

                     'distance': prediction[1],
                     'coords': {
                           'x': str(faces[0][0]),
                           'y': str(faces[0][1]),
                           'width': str(faces[0][2]),
                           'height': str(faces[0][3])
                              }
                        }
                      }

            dist = result['face']['distance']
            print "Known Face DISTANCE" , dist

            cv2.putText(frame,
                 '%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),
                 (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,1,(255, 255, 0))
       else:
            print "for prediction more than 600"
            print "prediction", prediction 
            result = {
                      'face': {

                             'distance': prediction[1],
                             'coords': {
                             'x': str(faces[0][0]),
                             'y': str(faces[0][1]),
                             'width': str(faces[0][2]),
                             'height': str(faces[0][3])
                                       }
                             }
                    }
          dist = result['face']['distance']
          print "UNKNOWN FACE" , dist
          cv2.putText(frame,
              'Unknown',
              (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(255, 255, 0))
         pin=sorted([int(n[:n.find('.')]) for n in os.listdir(path2)
                if n[0]!='.' ]+[0])[-1] + 1
         cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.jpg' % (path2, pin), eq)

    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Too much code for a simple question, with few comments on it. Anyway, if you are checking all the matches with 'faces', you can do a `break`  when the `if` statement is _True_

Comment: @Jalo i have added some comments to make it easier to understand. secondly i do not want to stop the whole process/script. i just want to stop recognition but as soon as any other face is detected face recognition should do its work.

Comment: firstly, which is exactly the piece of code that is repeating 'again and again'? is it the line `prediction = model.predict(eq)`? Did you copy well the code? I see 2 indentation errors in the code (In the line I just mentioned and 2 after it), are they typing errors? Finally, if you write `break` it won't stop the whole script, just the corresponding `for` or `while` loop

Comment: @Jalo yes it is the line `prediction = model.predict(eq)` which is repeating it self but i do not want it to be repeated all the time. I guess these indentation errors were made while copying the code i have edited them too. I did place the break for recognition but it did not work. ehich is why i was asking for help. actually i want to run the detection. i just want to stop the part of the code after `prediction = model.predict(eq)` .   this line should run only once for every face detected.  
Thankyu so much :)